# More than 10 000 000 sesssions in Universal Analytics

Tags: universal-analytics, large-data-volumes

We have a resource of our client with more than 10 000 000 sessions (not hits) per month. Is it possible that they will contact our client soon and ask him to use a paid account in Universal Analytics (or to reduce the data volume)?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this conversation a while ago and yes, if your clients exceeds the hit quota on an ongoing basis Google reserves the right to contact him an make him either buy the commercial version of Google Analytics, reduce the processing volume by [implementing a sample rate limit](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sampleRate) (which would mean you client does not track all their visitors) or, after a period of non-compliance, terminate the account. FWIW, they assured us that they would never shut down an account without prior notice as long as messages to the e-mail-adresses in the account in question elicit a response.